# Connect Rails app and browserless/chrome container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to use the `browserless/chrome` docker image and connect to it from a Ruby on Rails (6.0) app running in another docker container. I'm having difficulty getting the two to connect.

The browserless container is running properly (I know because I can access the web debug interface it comes with).

In the Rails app, I am trying to use `capybara` with `selenium-webdriver` to drive a headless chrome instance.

I am getting errors saying that either it can't connect or that it cannot post to '/session', which I think means it's properly connecting but can't initialize a session within chrome for some reason.

Below is my current configuration + code:

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: sync-plus.web:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      RACK_ENV: development
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
      DATABASE_URL_TEST: postgres://postgres:super@postgres:5432/salesync_test
    command: "bin/puma -C config/puma.rb"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mailcatcher
      - redis

  sidekiq:
    image: sync-plus.web:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      RACK_ENV: development
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
      DATABASE_URL_TEST: postgres://postgres:super@postgres:5432/salesync_test
    command: "bundle exec sidekiq"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mailcatcher
      - web
      - redis

  guard:
    image: sync-plus.web:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      RACK_ENV: test
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/1
      DATABASE_URL_TEST: postgres://postgres:super@postgres:5432/salesync_test
    command: "bin/rspec"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: super

  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher:latest
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"

  browserless:
    image: browserless/chrome:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:3000"

volumes:
  postgres_volume:
  redis:
```

```
#rails_helper.rb
...
require "rspec/rails"

# This require needs to be below the rspec/rails require
require 'capybara/rails'
...
```

I am using an Rspec test to check if the browserless connection/driving is functional:

```
#browserless_spec.rb

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe 'Browserless', type: :feature do
  describe "Connection" do
    it "can connect to browserless container" do

      #selenium webdriver looks at localhost:4444 by default
      driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote

      
      driver.visit("/users/sign_in")
      expect(page).to have_selector("btn btn-outline-light my-2")
    end
  end
end
```

I can't seem to find any solid solutions or leads elsewhere, so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!